# EntityTypeManager database transaction

Tags: 8, entities, database

I am using `\Drupal::EntityTypeManager()` in Drupal 8 to save data provided from a form into a content type. The following code saves the information in the content type `news`:

```
$data = [
  'type' => 'news',
  'title' => $title,
  'body' => ['value' => $content, 'format' => $format],
];

$node = \Drupal::EntityTypeManager()
  ->getStorage('node')
  ->create($data);
$node->save();
```

Now I need to get the nodeID of the node that was just saved. How do I do that ? Furthermore, I need to insert another set of data into a second content type that needs to store the nodeID I just mentioned.

```
$node2 = \Drupal::EntityTypeManager()
  ->getStorage('node')
  // $data2 contains the $node->id()
  ->create($data2);
$node2->save();
```

Outside of Drupal I am used to mysql transactions to make sure that both things only get stored together and get rolled back if there is an error with either of them. Is there a way to achieve this 'all-or-nothing' functionality with `\Drupal::EntityTypeManager()`?

Do I genrally need to put this in a `try{}catch{}` block in Drupal?

Comment: Isn't it added to the object you just saved? Did you try calling `$node->id();` to fetch the node id?

Comment: absolutely correct, I missed that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create the node without saving it.  You wouldn't really need a try catch if you know what types of data you're saving.

```
    $node = \Drupal::EntityTypeManager()->getStorage('node')->create([
      'type' => 'news',
      'title' => "hello world",
      'field_some_textfield' => "Here's some text",
    ]);

    $node->set('status', 1);
    $node->set('field_site_section', [['target_id' => 6]]);
    $node->set('field_first_name', $data->firstName);
    if (!empty($data->middleName)) {
      $node->set('field_middle_name', $data->middleName);
    }
    $node->set('field_last_name', $data->lastName);
```

When you're satisfied that your node is set up properly, then you can call:

```
$node->save();
```

At this point, you can get the node id this way:

```
$nid = $node->id();
```

Comment: Nice, I did not know that before. But how does this make sure that for the 2 nodes ($node and the second $node2 I need to save) I have a transaction kind of behavior? Doing $node->save(); $node2->save(); isn't really robust in case things break after $node->save(), is it ?

Comment: The only way to get a node id to add to $node2 is to save the first node.  So you could add a code that would run $node->delete() if updating $node2 failed.